# best practices for AJAX framework implementation

Tags: java, ajax

What are the best-practices in implementation of AJAX framework and handling 'special' cases as:

- Session timeout on AJAX call (redirect to login page, error, ignore...)
- Server exceptions in AJAX request
- Server session state in multiple following AJAX calls
- Browser reload of page where AJAX calls has been made
- Browser back to page where AJAX calls has been made
- Delayed AJAX requests
- ...

Any articles, books, notices, ... will be helpful. Either general AJAX or specialized for some server side implemetations.

(My case is java, component based state-full UI framework, AJAH's like AJAX (asynchronous java-script and HTML)

NOTE: I've been googling for a while and all I've found are articles about how AJAX is cool or how to implement it with help of some framework. Nothing about how to write such framework, what are general problems when doing it, etc...

Comment: Your question gives the impression that you want to create an AJAX framework yourself. Is that really what you want or do you want to create an application using an AJAX framework?

Comment: Yes, the impression has been right. I want to create an AJAX framework. In fact I already have one and want to enhance it. It's part of company's proprietary web framework that has been started ages ago when there wasn't any component based frameworks in Java world...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a website or a book with all theses answers but perhaps have some clue.

I already had the session problem and here's what I thought :

- I think the best way to handle the
  session timeout is to display a
  message to user, several minutes before the
  timeout, saying that the
  session will soon expire which means he will lost what he did. The message
  should contain an ajax link which
  will send a request to server in order to clear the session timeout and
  close that message.
- In the case of the user is not in
  front of it's screen and the session timeout has expired, you may display close the previous message and display another one saying that the session has expired, and propose to reload the page by saving user's input data if any (or at least, say him that he will lost what he eventually just type).

In oder to handle the browser "back" or "reload" action when you used Ajax, I think you should take a look about [reallysimplehistory](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) project which allows you to set a state about a piece of URL.

Also, I read the book [Ajax Patterns and Best Practices](http://ajaxian.com/archives/book-review-ajax-patterns-and-best-practices) which gives me some piece of advice about specific Ajax problems. Perhaps that will help you too.

Comment: thx for answer. I personally don't like the idea of message several minute before session timeout. I think 99% of users are not present and will not click to get session back...
There are some great posts about history and bookmarking at RSH home page. thx